# How to pass an array to shared memory in windows c/c++

Tags: c

If pMapMen is 7 elements long, how would I pass more than one element at a time. The below code passes one element.

```
//Create memory mapped file - pMapMem
 pMapMem[1] = (int*)MapViewOfFile( 
                       hMap,                   // Handle to map object
                       FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,    // Read/Write permisssion
                       0, 
                       0, 
                       BYTES_TO_MAP);
```

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple mapped views? A common method is to use a single structure (which may contain other structures, arrays, elements, ... ), for all of mapped memory, which would only require one base pointer for each process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file only contains array of `NUM_ELEM` elements, and their type is `myelement_t` struct, you could do something like this:

```
#define BYTES_TO_MAP (NUM_ELEM * sizeof(myelement_t))

myelement_t *elem;
void *mmapped = MapViewOfFile( 
                       hMap,                   // Handle to map object
                       FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,    // Read/Write permisssion
                       0, 
                       0, 
                       BYTES_TO_MAP);

if(NULL != mmapped) {
  elem = (myelement_t *) mmapped;
  for(i= 0; i < NUM_ELEM; i++) {
    printelem(elem[i]);
  }
}
```

If your code passes only 1 element, then it's probably because you've mapped only 1 element i.e. `BYTES_TO_MAP` is equal to length of 1 element

Comment: My array only has integers, I'm declearing it as int     *pMapMem[7];

Comment: int *pMapMem[7]; does not declare an array of integers. Its an array of 7 pointers(to integers).

Comment: Yeah I'm a little lost. Is your example c++?

Comment: @Gozmit - the example is C code. For your case, change myelement_t to int. printelem() could be any function that you create, or you could just use printf.